# Can't download artifact from another pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I got two AzureDevops pipelines in my project:

Build:

```
pool:
  name: DashboardBuild
steps:

- script: 'npm run build-dashboard'
  displayName: 'Build all sites'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\s\dist\'
    publishLocation: FilePath
    TargetPath: 'D:\DashboardsBuilds'
```

DashboardBuild is custom server where I want to build the solution.
This pipeline runs fine and will produce the artifact to D:\DashboardsBuilds\drop as expected

Deploy:

```
trigger:
- none

stages:
  - stage: DeployWebsite
    displayName: 'Deploy website'
    pool:
      name: DashboardBuild
    jobs:
    
    - deployment: DeployWebsite
      displayName: 'Deploy website'
      environment: 'DashboardPc.Test'
      strategy:
       runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
               - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
                 inputs:
                   buildType: 'specific'
                   project: 'e33acf52-c055-4d40-ba69-e9970253a87e'
                   pipeline: '36'
                   buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
                   downloadType: 'single'
                   artifactName: 'drop'
                   downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

The project: 'e33acf52-c055-4d40-ba69-e9970253a87e' is referencing ProjectName that both pipelines are under.
The pipeline: '36' is referencing 'Build' pipeline

I'm expecting this to download the already build latest artifact 'drop' from 'Build' pipeline and put them onto 'DashboardPc.Test' '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

I'm getting error:
##[error]Could not find a part of the path 'D:\DashboardsBuilds\drop'.

The problem is that it is looking for 'D:\DashboardsBuilds\drop' directory on 'DashboardPc.Test' server where they are located on 'DashboardBuild'

How can I download already buit artifacts from 'DashboardBuild' to 'DashboardPc.Test'?

Comment: What does the DownloadBuildArtifacts@1 task report to the logs?

Comment: ##[error]Could not find a part of the path 'D:\DashboardsBuilds\drop'. If I understand correctly this doesn't work as the Artifact is published to self hosted pool DashboardBuild. To get it working I have changed it to vmImage: windows-latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build job and the deploy job run on different agent machines.

- In the build job, you directly publish the artifacts to the directory "**`D:\DashboardsBuilds\drop`**" on the build agent machine. This directory is not a shared path (file share path).
- In the deploy job, the deploy agent machine cannot directly access the filesystem on build agent machine, it will try to search for the directory "**`D:\DashboardsBuilds\drop`**" on itself.

---

For your case, you can try like as below:

1. You first need to map a file share that can be accessible from both the build agent machine and the deploy agent machine.
2. In the build job, use the **PublishBuildArtifacts** task to publish the artifacts to the file share.
3. In the deploy job, you can use the **DownloadBuildArtifacts** task to access the file share and download the specified artifacts.

---

**EDIT:**

If you do not want to use the file share path, you can try to install the build agent and deploy agent on the same machine so that the two agents can directly access the directory "**`D:\DashboardsBuilds\drop`**" on the agent machine. Otherwise, you might need to publish the artifacts to Azure Pipelines by using the default setting "**`publishLocation: Container`**" on the **`PublishBuildArtifacts`** task.

```yaml
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\s\dist\'
    publishLocation: Container
```

---

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid the file share path. Looks like mine problem is that my DashboardBuild server is a self hosting virtual machine. I have switched this so its build with  vmImage: windows-latest for both Buid and Deploy pipeline. As soon as I have done that it started to work.

Comment: @MikeF, If you do not want to use the file share path, you can try to install the build agent and deploy agent on the same machine so that the two agents can directly access the directory "`D:\DashboardsBuilds\drop`" on the agent machine. Otherwise, you might need to publish the artifacts to Azure Pipelines by using the default setting "**`publishLocation: Container`**" on the **`PublishBuildArtifacts`** task (see **EDIT**).

Comment: The build agent and deploy agent option is very inefficient in my scenario as I want to distribute this artifact to 12 sites. I did use the Azure Pipelines by using the default setting "publishLocation: Container" on the PublishBuildArtifacts task. This way I can access it from every site. The initial idea was to have self hosting build server that will deploy the code (with slight modification) to all the sites.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the rest call within your pipeline as below

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=5.0
```

Official Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-5.0#create-the-request

Comment: I believe this will not work as the Artifact is published to self hosted pool.

Answer (score 0):

Since your *DownloadBuildArtifacts@1* task is properly configured to download from the other pipeline's artifact, another alternative is to change the publishing pipeline to use the built-in pipeline storage for the build artifact.

```yaml
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\s\dist\'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have code a sample for consume across pipeline artifacts. As mentioned in the documentation

> Using Azure Pipelines, you can download artifacts from earlier stages in your pipeline or from another pipeline. You can also publish your artifact to a file share or make it available as a pipeline artifact. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

`azure-pipelines-build.yml`

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/testBuildFolder'    # Specifies the path of the file or directory to publish
    artifact: 'wbDrop'
```

`azure-pipelines-consumeBuild.yml`

```
parameters:
- name: PublishArtifacts_PiplineProjectName
  default: 'Test'
- name: PublishArtifacts_PiplineDefinitionId
  default: ''
- name: PublishArtifacts_PiplineRunId
  default: ''

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  displayName: 'Download the drop from antoher pipeline'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/filedownload'
    # Specifies the path of the file or directory to publish
    artifact: 'wbDrop'
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: ${{ parameters.PublishArtifacts_PiplineProjectName }}       # build pipeline project
    definition: ${{ parameters.PublishArtifacts_PiplineDefinitionId }}   # which pipeline publish the artifacts
    pipelineId: ${{ parameters.PublishArtifacts_PiplineRunId }}          # which pipeline run publishj the artifacts. alias to buildId or runId

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Check file already downloaded'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: dir '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/filedownload'
```

my folder pattern:

[image]

where you can get the ids:

- [get pipeline definition id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines#to-find-the-definitionid-for-a-specific-pipeline-definition)
- [get pipeline run id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines#to-find-the-buildid-for-a-specific-pipeline-run)

my result:

[image]